# JavaScript Date toLocaleTimeString() not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, localization

I have two timers on a page.  One displays the Local Time and the other is a Timer from zero.

```
function go()
{
    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval( updateTime, 1000);
}     

function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date();              
    sessionTime = new Date(Date.now() - startTime);      

    $("#session").text(checkTime(sessionTime.getHours()) + ":" +
        checkTime(sessionTime.getMinutes()) + ":" +
        checkTime(sessionTime.getSeconds()));


    $("#timer").text(checkTime(now.getHours()) + ":" + 
        checkTime(now.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
        checkTime(now.getSeconds())); 
};

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i <10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Unfortunately the element `#sessionLocale` returns `01:00:00` instead of the `00:00:00` I am expecting.

I delete the startTime from the 'now' time.  I then use that to extract the hours, minutes and seconds which gives me 00:00:00.  But if I use the toLocaleTimeString I get 01:00:00.

I want to use toLocaleTimeString for it's localisation options.
Any ideas?

Comment: Um, `Date` objects don't represent time intervals/differences? How did you expect that to work in the first place?

Comment: Yes but I am deleting the startTime from the Current time and if I return that in hours, minutes and seconds I get: 00:00:00. But if I use toLocaleTimeString() I get 01:00:00.  Probably something obvious!

    sessionTime = new Date(Date.now() - startTime);

Comment: If you subtract times from each other, you get a millisecond value. If you put that in a new `Date` object, you get some date object around Jan 01 1970. Which has some time value, and if you output that depending on your locale it might output anything.

Comment: You are at 1970 - 01 - 01 00:00:00 UTC so my guess is that you are living in Central Europe and your timezone is GMT + 1 this is why 01:00:00 is the starting point.

Comment: @Spectator: That seemed like what the problem was but when I return sessionTime, I get : Thu Jan 01 1970 00:03:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) but if I do sessionTime.toLocaleTimeString I get 01:00:00.  We are not currently +1 hour.  That happens at the end of March.

Comment: Hmm so you are in the GMT +0000 timezone? The +1 isn't from the summertime. It is the standard time offset from the GMT. You can see the timeoffset with date.date.getTimezoneOffset() it is in minutes.

Comment: Okay then to be double sure use the getUTCHours function, as in my answer. This will work in all cases even if you are in a different Timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```js
function go()
{
    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval( updateTime, 1000);
}     

function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date();              
    sessionTime = new Date(Date.now() - startTime);

    // sessionTime.setHours(00);
    console.log();
    sessionTimeL = new Date(Date.now() - startTime);

    $("#session").text(checkTime(sessionTime.getUTCHours()) + ":" +
        checkTime(sessionTime.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" +
        checkTime(sessionTime.getUTCSeconds()));
    $("#sessionLocale").text(
      pad(Math.floor(sessionTimeL * 1 / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24), 2) + ':' +
      pad(Math.floor(sessionTimeL * 1 / (1000 * 60) % 60), 2) + ':' +
      pad(Math.floor(sessionTimeL * 1 / (1000) % 60), 2)
    );

    $("#timer").text(checkTime(now.getHours()) + ":" + 
        checkTime(now.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
        checkTime(now.getSeconds())); 

    console.log(sessionTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit'
    }));
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i <10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

go();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="session"></div>
  <div id="sessionLocale"></div>
  <div id="timer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So here is the why. You are creating a new Date with 0 msec witch is equal to 1970 - 01 - 01 00:00:00 UTC so when you are in a different timeZone then UTC you get the Offset.

You can either calculate the time difference or you could get the UTC hours with date.getUTCHours(). Or you get the UTC string and regex the time from it. The solution I did is more secure to work.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Dates on Javascript can be troublesome sometimes due to the offset changing in different regions.

There's a library called [DataJS](http://www.datejs.com/) which is super easy to implement, has really amazing performance and expands on the Date methods, adding functionality you might otherwise have to implement on your own.

For example to get the difference between two dates:

```
var futureDate = new Date().add({months: 5, days: 4, hours: 3, minutes: 2, seconds: 1}); 

var now = new Date();

var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(futureDate - now);

console.log("Days:", timeSpan.getDays()); console.log("Hours:", timeSpan.getHours()); console.log("Minutes:", timeSpan.getMinutes()); console.log("Seconds:", timeSpan.getSeconds());
```

That way you can get a more human readable time span between two dates.

Check the latest version in the SVN at https://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/.